# Bootstrap can't change select's selected value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, .net-core, bootstrap-4

I have a select, user choose a filter from it then press search button. My problem is after user clicked search button, in my controller, I send filter to view with `ViewBag` and I want selected value to stay as what chosen lastly, but selected value is always first option.

How I send from controller:

```
ViewBag.FilterName = filter.F;
```

It is either `"-1","0","1" or "2"` all strings.

Select from view:

```
<select style="margin-top: 6px; width:auto;" class="" id="f" name="f" >
                                <option value="0">Filtrele</option>
                                <option value="1">Kitap Adı</option>
                                <option value="2">Yazar</option>
                            </select>
```

My script in the same view:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#f option[value=@(ViewBag.FilterName ?? "-1")]').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
</script>
```

What I tried so far:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#f option[value=@(ViewBag.FilterName ?? "-1")]').attr('selected', true);
    }
</script>
```

---

(with adding class = "selectpicker")

```
$('select[name=f]').val(@ViewBag.FilterName);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')
```

---

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', @ViewBag.FilterName);
```

None of these solved my problem. Hope I could explain my problem clearly. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
[image]

I am getting values.

Comment: Are you running the JS code in a .js file? If so it won't work as the Razor code won't be interpreted there, the output will literally be `@(ViewBag.FilterName...`. If you are running this in an MVC view, then please show the actual HTML output to verify the selector is valid.

Comment: It's in MVC view, I am getting ViewBag value correctly. Added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows

but before that please confirm that

```
@ViewBag.FilterName
```

has some values

```
$("#f").val(@ViewBag.FilterName).trigger('change')
```